# angular ng-select and add event

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I'm using [`ng-select`](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) and on selected item fire the callback which does some logic. I face the problem, that `(add)` event does not fire when I choose the item from the list and I use the `(change)` event instead. But if I use one item twice from the list the change event not fire, because it's a change event.

```
<ng-select 
    [clearSearchOnAdd]="true"
    (change)="changeLeagueOwner($event)"
    (add)="test()" ---> nothing here
    [clearable]="false"
    [items]="adminLeagueMembers"
    bindLabel="display_name">
</ng-select>
```

Answer (score 3):

`change` event only get triggered when the value changes. If you want to fire an event if the same item select twice then use the click function,

```
<ng-select 
    [clearSearchOnAdd]="true"
    (click)="changeLeagueOwner($event)"
    (add)="test()" ---> nothing here
    [clearable]="false"
    [items]="adminLeagueMembers"
    bindLabel="display_name">
</ng-select>
```

Comment: if i use (click) event the callback function fire when i open the list, before i even choose some item from list

Answer (score 2):

Just for completion's sake, the reason why `(add)` is not working in your example is described in [the documentation](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#outputs):

> (add) is fired when item is added while [multiple]="true". Outputs added item

Answer (score 0):

After some research i find a solution:

In order that `(add)` event not working, and i using `(change)` instead, i add
`ElementRef` to list

```
<ng-select 
    #changeowner       
</ng-select>
```

Inside my component:

```
@ViewChild ('changeowner') changeOwnerRef: ElementRef;
```

and inside callback just set `false` to `selected` property of selected item

```
this.changeOwnerRef['itemsList']['_items'].forEach((item) => {
    for (const value in item) {
      if (value === 'selected') {
        item[value] = false;
      }
    }
});
```